# Using string as part of a variable

Tags: c#

I want to use a string as part of a variable.

For example in the code below I have a String called `productLine`. I want to use the value in this string to create a variable name and to call to the property "Value" on this variable. I want to keep switching the value in 'productLine', and therefore keep switching the variable who's value method is called.

Is there a way to do this or will I need to rewrite the code and take a different approach?

```
foreach (string productLine in productLineData)
{
    string templateKey = "{{" + productLine + "}}";
    string templateValue = "";
    if (productRow.productLine.Value != null)
        templateValue = productRow.productLine.Value.ToString();
    productRowText = productRowText.Replace(templateKey, templateValue);
}
```

`productRow` is a model which contains the properties I wish to use.

**EDIT:**

`productLine` contains a String value. For example it contains `productName` at first. At that point I want to call `productRow.productName.Value`. Next 'productLine' contains `productPrice`. At that point I want to call `productRow.productPrice.Value`. etc.

Comment: The question is currently quite confusing(probably just a language issue). You want to use a string as part of a variable? You have `productLine` which is filled with a string? You want to keep switching between  from where value is called? You need to explain it in other words or with examples.

Comment: It might just be my lack of understanding, but i do not really see how that other question is the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using reflection as romain-aga suggested.

```
 using System.Reflection;


    //...
    foreach (string productLine in productLineData)
    {
        string templateKey = "{{" + productLine + "}}";
        string templateValue = string.Empty;
        object value =  productRow?.GetType()?.GetProperty(productLine)?.GetValue(productRow, null);
        if (value != null)
            templateValue = value.ToString();
        productRowText = productRowText.Replace(templateKey, templateValue);
    }
    //...
```

Comment: Good answer. I would have just added a test to check if  `productRow.GetType().GetProperty(productLine)` is not null before calling `GetValue`:-)

Comment: You are right. See edit using new language feature.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable you want to address is a property of a class (i.e. a member) then Reflection will allow you to get/set its value by using the string of its name. If the variable is just a function scoped symbol (i.e. `string myVar = "";` ) then it doesn't exist at runtime and cannot be accessed.